# rg.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: bse_clientcontact is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: bse_clientcontact is not mapped [select cc from bse_clientcontact cc where cc.clientId=:id].

1.model class

```
package com.si.bse.model;

 @Entity

 @Table(name = "BSE_CLIENTCONTACT", uniqueConstraints =

{

 @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})



public class ClientContact 

      {


 @Id 

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

  @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
  @NotNull

private long clientContactId;

@Column(name = "CLIENTCONTACTNAME", nullable = false)
@NotNull @NotEmpty
private String clientContactName;

@Column(name = "CLIENTCONTACTNUMBER", nullable = false)
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
private String clientContactNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="client_Id")
private Client client;

public ClientContact(){}

public long getClientContactId() {
    return clientContactId;
}

public void setClientContactId(long clientContactId) {
    this.clientContactId = clientContactId;
}

public String getClientContactName() {
    return clientContactName;
}

public void setClientContactName(String clientContactName) {
    this.clientContactName = clientContactName;
}

public String getClientContactNumber() {
    return clientContactNumber;
}

public void setClientContactNumber(String clientContactNumber) {
    this.clientContactNumber = clientContactNumber;
}

public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
```

}

2.dao implation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
@Override
public Client getClientListDetail(long id) {



    //Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Client clientList =  (Client) getCurrentSession().load(Client.class, id);  
    return clientList;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public ClientContact getClientContact(long id) {
    //Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    ClientContact clientContactList =  (ClientContact) getCurrentSession().createQuery("select cc from bse_clientcontact cc where cc.clientId=:id").setParameter("id", id).uniqueResult();

    return clientContactList;
}
```

3.Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "singleView.do")
public String  navigateToProductView( Map<String,Object>map)

{

/*  if(result.hasErrors()){
        ModelAndView model1=new ModelAndView("ADD");
        return model1;

    }*/

    int clientId=13;// Integer.parseInt(id);
    System.out.println("it is controller..single view");
    Client clientList = searchServices.getClientListDetail(clientId);
    ClientContact clientContact = searchServices.getClientContact(clientId);
//  ClientImage clientImage = searchServices.getClientImage(clientId);
    //ClientVideo clientVideo = searchServices.getClientVideo(clientId);
    ClientCategory clientCategory = searchServices.getClientCategory(clientId);

    //System.out.println(clientList.getClientId());
    //System.out.println(clientList.getClientName());

    map.put("clientList", clientList);      
    map.put("clientContact", clientContact);
//  map.put("clientImage", clientImage);
    //map.put("clientVideo", clientVideo);
    map.put("clientCategory", clientCategory);
    System.out.println("single view.....");

    System.out.println("id----:"+clientId);
    map.put("popularSearchList", popularSearchServices.getPopularSearchList());
    return "singleProductView";
}
```

4.this is the error

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/bse] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: bse_clientcontact is not mapped [select cc from bse_clientcontact cc where cc.clientId=:id]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: bse_clientcontact is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at com.si.bse.dao.impl.SearchDaoImpl.getClientContact(SearchDaoImpl.java:123)
    at com.si.bse.services.impl.SearchServicesImpl.getClientContact(SearchServicesImpl.java:44)
    at com.si.bse.controller.Searchcontroller.navigateToProductView(Searchcontroller.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT cc
FROM CLIENTCONTACT cc
WHERE cc.clientContactId= :Id
```

Please note that when you use JPQL or HQL, you are dealing with entities, are not tables, so you should `SELECT` from `CLIENTCONTACT` entity and not the table `BSE_CLIENTCONTACT` for which it is mapped.

Comment: sir still i am getting the error CLIENTCONTACT is not mapped..:(

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: sir i was using the table name so i was getting the error.thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes obviously, but I was wondering what was wrong with the query I've provided that did not solve your problem.

Comment: i have written this on and it works...FROM ClientContact  cc WHERE cc.id= :id